# Speeding up row counting and join 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 tables, coupons and coupon_click
 This query is taking really a long time:

```
$this->db->select('coupons.*, COUNT(coupon_click.coupon_id) max_rating');
$this->db->from('coupons');
$this->db->join('coupon_click', 'coupons.id = coupon_click.coupon_id');
$this->db->where('coupons.enabled',1);
$this->db->group_by(array("coupons.id", "coupon_click.coupon_id")); 
$this->db->order_by('date_added','desc');
$top_coupons =$this->db->get()->result();
```

Any help please how to speed up this query?
Thanks guys

Comment: Is there a index on coupons.enabled ?

Comment: You can remove coupons.* and just put those fields those you want from the database for use like coupons.name, coupons.date etc.... It can help you to speeding up your result.

Comment: There's no way to correctly advise you on how to make it faster since you only posted PHP code. There's no info about hardware being used, what MySQL optimizer is trying to do nor what you've indexed. Indexes help MySQL to utilize the hardware less, by organizing data into ordered structures - therefore it can utilize less hardware resources to obtain relevant data. Even if you manage to index everything, you still have to pay attention on what type of hardware you're running all of that. Try to post the table create statements and output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @BerndBuffen the indexes are website_id, expiry_date and id, as for the removal of  remove coupons.* it didn't help !